# auto resizing the height of the views

Tags: titanium-alloy

```
    <ScrollView id="scrollGeneric" height ='auto' visible='false'>
        <View id="formView" height='auto'>
            <View id='distSlider' top='0' height='100'>
                <Label id="lblGeneric" >
                    Search Distance:
                </Label>
                <Slider id="sliderDistance" top="50" min="2" max="80" width="50%"/>
                <Label id="sliderDistanceText" width='auto' top="50" right="40" />
                <Label id="sliderDistanceTextMeasure" width='auto' top="50" right="10" text="km" />
            </View>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

I have set the height auto for scrollView and formView. However whenever I add more views inside of the formView the size of the window does not expand vertically with it. It will eventually crop out the views that exceed the window height.

The only way to solve this is to manually specify the height of each view within the form view div.

Is there anyway I can avoid doing this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Ti.UI.SIZE instead for the height? As per the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View), "height:auto is not recommended for new development and will be deprecated in the future."